# AWK: match characters inside a captured group

Tags: regex, awk

For example, I have groups of citations within the text like these

```
Lorem ipsum \textbf{dolor} sit amet \cite{a,b,c,d,e}, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie urna et dui $\mu=\text{a b c}$ venenatis pretium. Duis sit amet metus orci \cite{a,b,c,d,e}. Nunc non lobortis arcu, sit amet imperdiet diam \cite{b,e,f}.
```

in a latex file. There can be many such paragraphs exist.

I want to match all commas `,` inside the `\cite` command to replace with another character, let say with `.` to have all the citations become   `\cite{a.b.c.d.e}`, `\cite{b.e.f}`, keeping the text the same.

So the output should be

```
 Lorem ipsum \textbf{dolor} sit amet \cite{a.b.c.d.e}, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie urna et dui $\mu=\text{a b c}$ venenatis pretium. Duis sit amet metus orci \cite{a.b.c.d.e}. Nunc non lobortis arcu, sit amet imperdiet diam \cite{b.e.f}.
```

Comment: With the input you posted `sed 's/,/./g'` is all you need so it that is NOT all you need then [edit] your question to provide sample input/output that more truly represents your real input.

Comment: _In the general case_, to match commas separating arguments in a latex macro argument list requires more subtlety and sophistication than even full parsers can provide. You're going to have to back off on your desires for a fire-and-forget solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear but is this what you want?

```
$ awk -F, 'match($0,/\\cite\{([^\}]+)/,a) {$0=a[1]; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NR, i, $i}' file
1 1 a
1 2 b
1 3 c
1 4 d
1 5 e
2 1 b
2 2 e
2 3 f
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(). If all you want to do is change the `,`s to `.`s that's just:

```
$ awk -F, 'match($0,/(.*\\cite\{)([^\}]+)(.*)/,a) {gsub(/,/,".",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2] a[3]} 1' file
\cite{a.b.c.d.e}
\cite{b.e.f}
```

Given your newly posted sample input output:

```
$ awk -v RS='[\\]cite[{][^}]+[}]' '{ORS=gensub(/,/,".","g",RT)} 1' file
Lorem ipsum \textbf{dolor} sit amet \cite{a.b.c.d.e}, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie urna et dui $\mu=\text{a b c}$ venenatis pretium. Duis sit amet metus orci \cite{a.b.c.d.e}. Nunc non lobortis arcu. sit amet imperdiet diam \cite{b.e.f}.
```

Still using GNU awk, this time for multi-char RS and RT.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to process the commas (replace them with another character). I updated the question again @Ed Morton.

Comment: `sed -E ':a; s/({[^,}]*),/\1./g; ta'`

Comment: It' d be much easier than that to do with sed what the OP shows instead of what he asks for but in any case GNU sed gives `sed: -e expression #1, char 23: Invalid preceding regular expression` when executing that command and all of those sed constructs except s and g became obsolete in themid-1970s when awk was invented anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got to the point of using `RS` but couldn't think of using `RT`.